# Jenkins docker cache not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, jenkins, docker

I'm trying to build a docker file under jenkins `docker build .`

Here is my docker file:

```
# DOCKER-VERSION 0.10.0
FROM docker-index.my.com/ruby:1.9.3
MAINTAINER my.com

# Never install a ruby gem docs
RUN echo "gem: --no-rdoc --no-ri" >> ~/.gemrc

RUN mkdir /my_app
WORKDIR /my_app

RUN gem install bundler
RUN gem install bluepill

ADD Gemfile /my_app/Gemfile
ADD Gemfile.lock /my_app/Gemfile.lock
RUN bundle install
ADD . /my_app
```

Note that I'm using the common caching method for bundle install, the cache works locally but not on jenkins build, what is the problem of running this under jenkins?

Comment: I never found any fundamental differences using Jenkins, or CLI-ing myself. What is your Jenkins setup?

Comment: I have typical Jenkins setup, minimal for the moment, this code runs on a execute shell step. Let say that syntactically there is no difference between execute shell and cli but in environment terms there are some, try executing env on both to see the differences, that might be my problem, but still not sure.

Comment: What happens if you manually run the script on the environment of Jenkins?

Comment: It reruns the bundle install step every time without using the cache

Comment: Which means the problem is not really Jenkins related, doesn't it? Apparently, that's just the way your Docker installation behaves on that environment.

Comment: Yeah!, it seems to be something wired with the environment, you got it now

Comment: @CarlosCastellanos So? How did you solve this?

Comment: It was all about the workspace wipeouts, new checkouts have different created time on files, so as a workaround I had to modify the build and as a first step change created time on files to match lastest commit date

Comment: Thanks, I found the same solution somewhere else. But for anyone else reading this, the date you have to set for each file is the date of the last commit where that file was modified, not the latest commit. https://github.com/dotcloud/docker/issues/5408